# How to get only direct child elements by jQuery function

Tags: jquery, parent-child

I have a table structure like this:

```
<table1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
        ...
      <td>
        <table2>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

In javascript, I have a variable `tbl` with value of `$(table1)`, and then I want to get all direct child elements (tr) of `<tbody>` of `table1`.
My code is :

```
$('tr', tb1)
```

Apparently it returns all `<tr>` elements in table1 and table2.
I think I can get by

```
$('tr', tb1).not(function(){return $(this).parent().parent()[0] != tb1;})
```

or this kind of logic.

I know `$('table1 > tbody > tr')` can get the direct child `tr`. Unfortunately I can not use this.

Anyone has good idea about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

`tbl.find("> tbody > tr")`

Comment: this is bralliant idea. $('> tbody > tr', tb1) also works for me. Thank you.

Comment: This is wonderful, I didn't know that you could use the direct child selector (`>`) without specifying anything in front of it. Thank you.

Comment: Note that for direct children that are only one level down you can simply use 'children([selector])'.

Comment: **DIRECT CHILDREN = one level down children**, therefore **http://api.jquery.com/children/** is the right answer, not find() - that one gets ALL descendants of element (filtered by selector)...

Comment: You should make your comment a separate answer jave.web as yours is THE correct answer.

Answer (score 30):

As @jave.web mentioned in the comments

To search through the direct children of an element use `.children()`. It will only search through the direct children and not traverse any deeper. http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly the reason why one should be careful with nesting tables. I really hope that you use them for data and not page layout.

Another issue that will probably ruin your day is using CSS selectors on nested tables... you basically have the same issue - you are unable to select TR elements of the outer table without selecting those inside the inner table, too. (You cannot use the child selector because it is not implemented in IE6)

This should work:

```
$("#table1 > tbody > tr")
```

However, I recommend that you hardcode the TBODY element, since you should not rely on the browser to create it for you.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

`$('tb1 > tr')`

Comment: This would only work if `tb1` were an HTML tag, which it is not; and if `tr` were a direct child of it (which it is not, it is a direct child of `<tbody>`).

Answer (score 1):

If you have ids of both elements and you want to find direct element use below code

```
$("#parent > #two")
```

If you want a nested search you can use find.
It is explained in detail here.
https://handyopinion.com/jquery-selector-find-nested-child-elements/