# Apply attr to div but not to children (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, attr

I have some html code looking like this:

```
<div id='main'>
    <a href=''>
    <div id='otherA'>
            <a href=''>
    </div>
    <div id='otherB'>
            <a href=''>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to apply the attribute "target" to elements of #main but not of #other using JQuery. I tried a few things and I think this is the closest I got but it does not seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main a').not(['#otherA a', '#otherB a']).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: tangential: just as an fyi, you should close your `<a></a>` tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get only direct child elements by jQuery function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687637/how-to-get-only-direct-child-elements-by-jquery-function)

Answer (score 6):

use `#main > a` as your selector.  That will only pick 'a' tags immediately under #main.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main > a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main'>
    <a href=''>main a</a>
    <div id='otherA'>
            <a href=''>asdsf</a>
    </div>
    <div id='otherB'>
            <a href=''>kjklsdf</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should remove the `.not(...)` method from the chain.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, I was just looking at that, too.  I'd have to clarify the OP's intent, but it seems like you are correct in his intentions (which is why I used the direct descendant selector).

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Removed the .not() method and used @ps2goat 's code but the links have the default behavior. Using '#main a' changes the attribute of all links to _blank but changing it to '#main > a' does nothing.

If it helps, I'm inserting this code into a CMSMS template and using the {cms_jquery} tag to get the source. However this should not be an issue since '#main a' works.

Comment: @user3394674, that seems like a different question since you didn't mention any other technologies.  I don't have any experience with `cmsms`, but depending on your environment, you may need to clear the cache on the server.  It could be a lot of other things, as well.  Rackspace cloud hosting, for example, requires additional work to clear the cache and restart asp.net applications compared to a traditional server setup.